# Exclude zero values from array comparison

Tags: arrays, excel

I've got this formula, which checks if there are any consecutive numbers within the range:

{=IF(SUM(--(ABS(C31:BI31-TRANSPOSE(C31:BI31))=1)),"Yes","No")}

It works perfectly, but I want to exclude zero values from conparison process.

4 6 2 8 0 9 - Result: "Yes"

0 1 7 5 9 2 - Result: "Yes", but it should be "No", since 0 and 1 should not be counted as consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(C31:BI31,1+1/(1/C31:BI31))),"Yes","No")`

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure that your original array formula is 'working perfectly'; you might want to double-check the results. Try this standard formula using the newer [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF)¹ to provide cyclic processing.

```
=IF(AGGREGATE(15, 6, ABS(C31:BH31-D31:BI31)/((C31:G31<>0)*(D31:BI31<>0)), 1)=1, "yes", "no")
```

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>